# Как реализовать задачу из макета

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

обучаюсь верстке , возник такой вопрос есть макет: [https://www.figma.com/file/rnIAwsECd4Qxltrz2p4NJa/Ветклиника?node-id=0%3A1&t=aPkamyHowD0px2qc-0](https://www.figma.com/file/rnIAwsECd4Qxltrz2p4NJa/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0?node-id=0%3A1&t=aPkamyHowD0px2qc-0)

В нем имеется блок "История пациентов", я немного не понимаю , как реализовать линию которая идет по центру , если вставлять её как svg или png она занимает слишком много места и вытесняет два блока с собаками за пределы контейнера при адаптиве.

Comment: Наказывать нужно дизайнеров за их уникальное видение сайта))). Интересно ещё, нужно ли учитывать, что текста там может стать больше или текст в макете уже будет статическим.

Comment: Ну допустим он будет статическим и тогда если учесть то, что 2 блока по 60% примерно, то картинка должна отображаться ну скажем на 10% дальше. Получается 70% + 70% = 140% - 100% = 40%. Значит картинка должна занимать 40% общей ширины контейнера по центру. Берём и создаём обычный div у родителя и через position: abolute; заставляем его плавать, далее выставляем ему ширину в 40% и центрируем left: 50%; margin-left: -20%; например. Или же можно его растянуть по всем направлениям и внутри создать ещё div, который будет центрироваться и которому задаём картинку 40% и background линии.

Comment: Далее лапки мы просто можем задавать блокам и они будут как раз прилегать к линиям проходящим по краям блоков.

Comment: А ещё лучше можно разделить линию на два блока и background одной картинке задать справой стороны, которой мы задаём ширину background-size:40%; и также задаём нижнему блоку, только слева также на 40%. И получится, что линии будут объединяться в нужных местах. А если даже там будет плюс минус пиксель расхождения линий, можно сделать так, что бы лапка скрывала место схождения линий.

Comment: Это мои методы, пришедшие в голову))

Comment: Делайте картинками раз дизайнер такой умный